# ¿Como alinear una imagen desde Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Buen dia,estoy intentando alinear (centrar) una imagen,pero no lo puedo conseguir.
Que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
var imagen =document.createElement("img");

imagen.src="ejemplo.jpg";
imagen.width="500";
imagen.height="300";
imagen.align="middle";


document.body.appendChild(imagen);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="Ejemplo1_ext.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

Agregando al elemento `img` los estilos:

`display: block;` y `margin: auto;`

Con esto se te centra:

```js
var imagen = document.createElement("img");
imagen.src="ejemplo.jpg";
imagen.width="500";
imagen.height="300";

imagen.style.display="block";
imagen.style.margin = "auto";

document.body.appendChild(imagen);
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas introducir la imagen dentro de un div y alinear el contenido del mismo centrado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_container" />
    <script> 
    var imagen =document.createElement("img");
    var div_contenedor = document.getElementById('div_container')

div_contenedor.width="100%";
div_contenedor.display="flex";
div_contenedor.align="center";
imagen.src="ejemplo.jpg";
imagen.width="500";
imagen.height="300";

div_contenedor.appendChild(imagen);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Escribe 
 `<center>`
aqui pones el comando de la imagen
y cierras el center
 `</center>`
automaticamente lo centra.

Comment: Para tu info: `<center>` es obsoleto [ver documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)